# Trouble setting up a virtual host for my local Laravel project

Tags: macos, apache, laravel, config, vhosts

I'm on OSX (El Capitan), using XAMPP and trying to use a local URL for my project. The idea is to run `http://projectname.local` in the browser and see that it points to `Programma's/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/public`, and the same if I enter `http://localhost/projectname/public`.

I've edited my hosts file like below:

```
127.0.0.1 projectname.local
```

I've followed the steps in [this tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-in-apache-on-mac-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) (enabling vhosts and setting one up)

This is the vhost configuration I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName projectname.local
    ServerAlias www.projectname.local
    DocumentRoot "/Programma's/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/public"
    ErrorLog "/Programma's/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/storage/logs/laravel.log"
    CustomLog "/Programma's/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/storage/logs/laravel_custom.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've flushed the cache using `dscacheutil -flushcache` and ran `apachectl restart`

But when I go to `http://projectname.local` I get the XAMPP dashboard rather than my project's Laravel welcome route.

Am I missing something?